# Postgres Rule to invalidate user passwords every 60 days

Tags: postgresql, passwords, rules

I am having some trouble invalidating user passwords every 60 days on my postgres database:

> `CREATE RULE user_expiration AS ON UPDATE TO users
>       DO INSTEAD
>       UPDATE user
>          SET user_expires = user_expires + '60'`

This will work every time the user changes their password, however it also works every time any update is issued on the records.  How can I ensure that it only updates on the change password event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is a better solution. As of version 9.0 it has per [column triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html), triggers that only fire when a certain column has been changed. In older versions you have to do the check inside the function, compare OLD.password and NEW.password before you deside to update the user_expires column.

Comment: I guess I should also ask how can we enforce that the password changes?

Comment: If you want to enforce a new password, if OLD.password = NEW.password then RAISE EXCEPTION in your trigger function.